# Firefox in docker - why can't my tests show activestorage blobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, selenium, docker-compose

I am writing a Rails application that supports the upload of images using ActiveStorage. I'm trying to write a system test, which is running in a Firefox. Firefox is being driven by Selenium over a network; ultimately it is installed inside a docker container.

I can write a system test that runs, and passes. The docker image I'm using supports interactively viewing the tests through OpenVNC - if you navigate to http://localhost:7900 in a browser, you can watch the tests run and interact with the test browser inside your host system browser.

The test I've written uploads a file, and checks that the file is uploaded by going to its dedicated "show" page. The page loads, and renders an image tag like

```html
<img src="http://web:37193/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBVZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--4c0a214932e528a8cea25a8f6bd6aad7b1e19994/rails-logo.svg">
```

Unfortunately, the image is blank in the browser and firefox reports that it "could not load the image". The source is definitely correct, and the network appears to be able to access it. If I add a break statement, and visit the given url in the test browser, it downloads the image just fine. By the way, it works fine in my development environment too. "37193" is the port Capybara is running on. "web" is the name of my rails container - I'll share my docker-compose below.

In my `spec/rails_helper.rb`,

```rb
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{ENV.fetch("HOSTNAME")}"
Capybara.default_host = "http://#{ENV.fetch("HOSTNAME")}"
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    # To watch the system tests interactively, visit localhost:7900
    driven_by :selenium, using: :firefox, screen_size: [1000,1000], options: { browser: :remote, url: 'http://firefox:4444' } 
    default_url_options[:host] = "#{ENV.fetch("HOSTNAME")}"
  end
```

and `docker-compose.yml`,

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: app
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    hostname: web
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/web
      - gems:/usr/local/bundle/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - firefox
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      DB_USER: root
      DB_NAME: app
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_HOST: db
  firefox:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox
    container_name: firefox
    ports:
      - "7900:7900"
      - "4444:4444"
    shm_size: "2gb"
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  gems:
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that I was using an SVG in tests. I only used a PNG when testing in my development environment, so never noticed the difference.

[An image with src that is an SVG *is valid*](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML). However, the image will only be correctly displayed if it has the content type header correctly set to be an image. To prevent XSS, [ActiveStorage will serve SVGs as application/octet-stream](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34665). For the case I'm testing (as the src for an `img` tag) that's unnecessary, [because scripts are disabled in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917008/xss-when-loading-untrusted-svg-using-img-tag). But if a user opens the image in a  new tab, they'd be vulnerable.